# AMP email is not being shown on GMAIL when sending it from AWS SES

Tags: gmail, amazon-ses, amp-email

When trying to see AMP mail that received from AWS SES using a python script - I'm able to see only the HTML part and not the AMP part. I'm using Gmail on a web/desktop (not mobile).

I've been able to get emails from the Gmail amp playground (https://amp.gmail.dev/playground/) but no from my domain (using the developer options for my domain).
I've been qualified for the pre-requirements, such as DKIM, DMARC, and SPF for my domain - I've attached a screenshot for this qualification.
I've made sure that my mail contains only the minimal AMP content, and the MIME tree is organized in good order (the AMP appears before the HTML).

This is the mail that I'm getting on Gmail:

```
Delivered-To: XXXXXX
Received: by 2002:adf:a2ce:0:0:0:0:0 with SMTP id t14csp9667034wra;
        Wed, 24 Jul 2019 00:50:42 -0700 (PDT)
X-Google-Smtp-Source: APXvYqwL5fGpFWN69lea/kepakqVoHfUbXMCm3R8pyGZW6SRJECQp/PJWL0TCVXLGPJH12TGQjPR
X-Received: by 2002:a50:e618:: with SMTP id y24mr69652549edm.142.1563954642448;
        Wed, 24 Jul 2019 00:50:42 -0700 (PDT)
ARC-Seal: i=1; a=rsa-sha256; t=1563954642; cv=none;
        d=google.com; s=arc-20160816;
        b=UIjwFXJ2f8uivW5CMliod/HeaqPgDEoPrLbJrGP1poPzSts/Ifv4asIs2Z5S1/oh5k
         vKkAijZY38K6osr/Vh6cYhQSl2mAX8PAj5yqsrcEqJJxpQK0WZ43LBvhw5yVCe/20xnm
         40XtgTp0pc2tQBnAxmMwdQs4/OebZx418KBGfoN3ZKStMU6S1vC69uadG3sQKyS9DfZ7
         ioQh8rooPSPYBqVGO80jfwx2p5XldxFyfPsmks7H+jIAFMov7i6Z4qA14GtBMwiHt13E
         5IgAtTDQneCR02krKwUCygYqYA1BU7U5F1wmNLUBQgfHgTSQwHRDv3HUIJVr4OwflMAx
         SMkg==
ARC-Message-Signature: i=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed; d=google.com; s=arc-20160816;
        h=feedback-id:date:message-id:to:from:subject:mime-version
         :dkim-signature:dkim-signature;
        bh=u8zKbqJArDsMg9NesmbsCH3q/TsRUKtAsLWu0QFVgOk=;
        b=zIaivJ+RHM+PI6cjXZ/qTgh4Jl1caUIrdM8ljwaH8x9DrQzZFiLBlKzdKVjoPNnaa8
         EIdn/+wIuPfvv7p02Gk4J71s41/Y3we6QIhsi9ZT7OGqopLb8fkcsqKLD4eD39MGfWOa
         cpfWPLW+B8UqO9v2gKRLn622Y4XYtH8flYZSfOftMqd1fboTz9vMY5L+clYttZLyUIdn
         0F59JyIB3oVtqqAqgfNje6ikbQvmGNxGob6UhUHt0EKQ7cS83S0NnV/P7KLtzQL17ld3
         iFN3QgyPDJlNz44G4YR2S220pD8EyXj+Btz/gi9omqml+moLnWKwGTZx97lFlnfDYp2O
         CXHA==
ARC-Authentication-Results: i=1; mx.google.com;
       dkim=pass header.i=@amiramen.com header.s=kz7cgy5efrrjqoowmf3kdany4nxqx5im header.b=yPnbkTNf;
       dkim=pass header.i=@amazonses.com header.s=ihchhvubuqgjsxyuhssfvqohv7z3u4hn header.b="Iv9/seaV";
       spf=pass (google.com: domain of 0102016c22f5fbce-fbba54af-35b0-4791-8877-32699f0c9e58-000000@eu-west-1.amazonses.com designates 54.240.7.37 as permitted sender) smtp.mailfrom=0102016c22f5fbce-fbba54af-35b0-4791-8877-32699f0c9e58-000000@eu-west-1.amazonses.com;
       dmarc=pass (p=QUARANTINE sp=QUARANTINE dis=NONE) header.from=amiramen.com
Return-Path: <0102016c22f5fbce-fbba54af-35b0-4791-8877-32699f0c9e58-000000@eu-west-1.amazonses.com>
Received: from a7-37.smtp-out.eu-west-1.amazonses.com (a7-37.smtp-out.eu-west-1.amazonses.com. [54.240.7.37])
        by mx.google.com with ESMTPS id h3si44113583wrx.267.2019.07.24.00.50.42
        for <mXXXXXX@gmail.com>
        (version=TLS1_2 cipher=ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA bits=128/128);
        Wed, 24 Jul 2019 00:50:42 -0700 (PDT)
Received-SPF: pass (google.com: domain of 0102016c22f5fbce-fbba54af-35b0-4791-8877-32699f0c9e58-000000@eu-west-1.amazonses.com designates 54.240.7.37 as permitted sender) client-ip=54.240.7.37;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com;
       dkim=pass header.i=@amiramen.com header.s=kz7cgy5efrrjqoowmf3kdany4nxqx5im header.b=yPnbkTNf;
       dkim=pass header.i=@amazonses.com header.s=ihchhvubuqgjsxyuhssfvqohv7z3u4hn header.b="Iv9/seaV";
       spf=pass (google.com: domain of 0102016c22f5fbce-fbba54af-35b0-4791-8877-32699f0c9e58-000000@eu-west-1.amazonses.com designates 54.240.7.37 as permitted sender) smtp.mailfrom=0102016c22f5fbce-fbba54af-35b0-4791-8877-32699f0c9e58-000000@eu-west-1.amazonses.com;
       dmarc=pass (p=QUARANTINE sp=QUARANTINE dis=NONE) header.from=amiramen.com
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; q=dns/txt; c=relaxed/simple;
    s=kz7cgy5efrrjqoowmf3kdany4nxqx5im; d=amiramen.com; t=1563954642;
    h=Content-Type:MIME-Version:Subject:From:To:Message-ID:Date;
    bh=u8zKbqJArDsMg9NesmbsCH3q/TsRUKtAsLWu0QFVgOk=;
    b=yPnbkTNfpn2pwgrkQMLEnU4/CGK+n+l9o1JAY0HRREmfweP9MVjXgKUTAJUbDSOC
    htjTUMZkICok+YIbJQBE/1+E+Za5vBaA9EYxiM4lFFfMoQeLvQWQ3l5r8FJ5Dquzb+h
    f/9E3oinynOL6JkGFDuASLVj8SBCWlaEEirGe6Uk=
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; q=dns/txt; c=relaxed/simple;
    s=ihchhvubuqgjsxyuhssfvqohv7z3u4hn; d=amazonses.com; t=1563954642;
    h=Content-Type:MIME-Version:Subject:From:To:Message-ID:Date:Feedback-ID;
    bh=u8zKbqJArDsMg9NesmbsCH3q/TsRUKtAsLWu0QFVgOk=;
    b=Iv9/seaVrzV/GlvUAzt4ux3U4GEmK8mvSIzyMDZDCF+/Q9KGiN56gFGPlIyYskk3
    5ENiJstFwKaOiSTEnyXgaCJAt6VxQlxsCwhvh2vKZIsT//p4d5ZDLv1PnuxkF78+e3i
    MkLha3uWP+RD2ayol6NnqGa0psfPYqkNn3EyMp/k=
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="===============2017642074=="
MIME-Version: 1.0
Subject: Hey, Wizard! Check out this dynamic email. #2
From: team@amiramen.com
To: XXXXX@gmail.com
Message-ID: <0102016c22f5fbce-fbba54af-35b0-4791-8877-32699f0c9e58-000000@eu-west-1.amazonses.com>
Date: Wed, 24 Jul 2019 07:50:41 +0000
X-SES-Outgoing: 2019.07.24-54.240.7.37
Feedback-ID: 1.eu-west-1.sAWpWQT4Rmzt8hbl9MsPloIFHFP494ZwRbh0mXyiwjI=:AmazonSES

--===============2017642074==
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="utf-8"
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64

THVtb3MhIEluIHBsYWluIHRleHQu

--===============2017642074==
Content-Type: text/html; charset="utf-8"
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64

PGh0bWw+Cjxib2R5PgogIDxwPkV4cGVsbGlhcm11cyEgSW4gSFRNTC48L3A+CjwvYm9keT4KPC9o
dG1sPgo=

--===============2017642074==
Content-Type: text/x-amp-html; charset="utf-8"
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64

PCFkb2N0eXBlIGh0bWw+CjxodG1sID1FMj05QT1BMTRlbWFpbD4KPGhlYWQ+CiAgPG1ldGEgY2hh
cnNldD0zRCJ1dGYtOCI+CiAgPHNjcmlwdCBhc3luYyBzcmM9M0QiaHR0cHM6Ly9jZG4uYW1wcHJv
amVjdC5vcmcvdjAuanMiPjwvc2NyaXB0PgogIDxzdHlsZSBhbXA0ZW1haWwtYm9pbGVycGxhdGU+
Ym9keXt2aXNpYmlsaXR5OmhpZGRlbn08L3N0eWxlPgo8L2hlYWQ+Cjxib2R5PgogIEhlbGxvLCBB
TVA0RU1BSUwgd29ybGQuCjwvYm9keT4KPC9odG1sPgo=

--===============2017642074==--
```

I expecting to see the AMP part in my Gmail web-desktop client. What did I do wrong?

Comment: Have you whitelisted your sender in Gmail settings?

Comment: Yep - I've added my domain as a sender in the Gmail settings :-)

Comment: Did you add the exact sender (seems to be `team@amiramen.com`)? Adding a whole domain is not possible.

Comment: Yep - I've added the specific mail to whitelist option in the developer mode.